# Set builder notation question

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have that $G$ is the set of real numbers of the form $m+n\sqrt2$ for $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$

So I think that it is either: $G=\{m+n\sqrt2 \in \mathbb{R},  m,n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ or $G=\{m+n\sqrt2 \in \mathbb{R}:  m,n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

I was just wondering which way round was the right one (if one of them is right!)? - I'm leaning towards the first one.

As a clarification, I know that the ":" in the second one reads "such that" but in the first one does the "," after $\mathbb{R}$ just read "and"?

Comment: I would personally write it the second way using either a : or a |.  There should be some clear divider between what the element looks like and the description about it.  Personally I wouldn't have the $\in \mathbb{R}$ on the left half either, I feel it distracts from the general form of the element.  Again, this is mostly personal preference.  $G = \{m + n\sqrt{2}~~|~~m,n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$

Comment: But do we not need to clarify on the left half that the element is part of $\mathbb{R}$ or is that then implied by the right half?

Comment: In most cases it is understood what type of number it is from context or from what types of numbers are possible that build it ($m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$ so it follows that $m+n\sqrt{2}\in\mathbb{R}$.  It is also true that $m+n\sqrt{2}\in\mathbb{C}$.  If I wanted only the positive results or felt the need to clarify, then I would usually put that on the right hand side: $G = \{m+n\sqrt{2}~~|~~m,n\in\mathbb{Z}~\text{and}~m+n\sqrt{2}\in\mathbb{R}^+\}$

Comment: I recommend looking at this wiki page on it all for more input than just my opinion: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation#Convention_of_annotating_the_variable_domain_on_the_left_of_the_.27such_that.27

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localised to be of any value to future readers.

Comment: @Davide Did you know that editing questions [catapults](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/151443/222340) them out of the review queue?

Comment: @Lord_Farin I didn't. And now I realize my edit actually does not change anything from the point of view of a closure. So I voted to close and it will be again (I hope) in the review queue.